# How to remove all traces of Crashlytics in Android app?

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

I am trying to move app to another agency. Ideally, it would be as simple as changing Organization API key and adding its secret into `fabric.properties` file. But this is not happening.

I have tried to remove all traces of Crashlytics so I can install it like the first time and pick the desired organisation. So I removed all Gradle entries, an entry from the `Manifest` and deleted `fabric.properties` file. I also logged out of Fabric plugin and restarted Android Studio, just in case. However this does not work. When I compile the app, it fills the old Organization data.

So how can I completely remove ALL traces of Crashlytics so the project looks just like before I installed it?

PS. also if someone knows how to move app to another organization (the method that does work), please share it with me.

Comment: I have been trying to do this for a few months and surprisingly I am still unable to remove all traces of Crashlytics once it has been installed. I managed to do this partially via Git history, but no easy way so far.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to do the same and would try doing the reverse from what is advised in the installation instructions [here](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install).
Meaning:

- removing the repository, plugin, and the dependencies from build.gradle;
- removing the keys (fabric.properties or app manifest xml);
- removing the initialization code;

I may add more details once actually trying to do this myself.